# sql query to find data which is not in database

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Table looks like that:

Users:

| User | DateFrom | DateTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1900-01-01 | 9999-01-01 |
| Kyle | 1900-01-01 | 2000-01-01 |

Table is quite big so I don't want to download it all to my app memory.

Now in app I have a list of users and dates. There are max 1000 of them. Now I would like to
make a query to check which of those users are not in a database.
I can do it one by one byt it will be 1000 queries.

For example I have an object:

User:John, Date: 2000 so the query would be like:

```
Select * from Users where User = 'John' and DateFrom < 2000 and DateTo > 2000
```

so result is: John, 1900-01-01 9999-01-01

So it means that this user is ok but for object:
User:Kyle, Date: 2005

result should be none so user is not ok.

WHat would be the best approach to get information about all my users in app in a n efficient way?

Comment: I think your query was wrong with the DateFrom > 2000 as the datefrom is 1900, which is lower.

Comment: Postgres or SQL Server? Please do not add tags for database that are not relevant

Comment: Is the date range filter static per query?...in other words, you'll only use one date range for multiple users, each time you query the table? Also, agreed with a_horse_with_no_name, remove the unused Tag from your Post. Microsoft SQL Server != PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list of values combined with a NOT EXISTS

```
select t.username as missing_user_name
from (
  values ('Kyle'), ('Arthur'), ('Tricia'), ('Ford'), ('Zaphod')
) as t(username) 
where not exists (select * 
                  from users u
                  where u.user_name = t.username 
                     and DateFrom >= date '2000-01-01'
                     and DateTo < date '2001-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table variable or temptable to insert your search values in. Then combine that with your User table. The ones with no FoundUser are the users you want to have.

```
DECLARE @UsersToFind TABLE
(
    [User] VARCHAR(50),
    DateToCheck DATE
)

INSERT INTO @UsersToFind
VALUES
(
    'John', '2000-01-01'
),
(
    'Kyle', '2005-01-01'
)

SELECT utf.[User],
       utf.DateToCheck,
       u.[User] AS FoundUser,
       u.DateFrom,
       u.Dateto
FROM @UsersToFind AS utf
LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON utf.[User] = u.[User]
    AND DateFrom < utf.DateToCheck
    AND DateTo > utf.DateToCheck
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now in app I have a list of users and dates.

Where is that list stored?
Is that in the database as well, or something completely separate?

Why is your list of Users *not* in the database?
I would expect to see a "master" table of Users, which is referenced by the table you show.

> Select * from Users where User = 'John' and DateFrom > 2000 and DateTo < 2000

Perhaps better:

```
select *  
from Users 
where User = ? 
and ? between DateFrom and DateTo
```

BTW: Never use `Select *` in Production Code.

Now; running 1000 queries is likely to be slow.

> Doing anything once takes a finite amount of time.
> Doing the same thing 1000 times takes [at least] 1000 times as long.

You *could* build them into one, big query using in ...

```
where User in ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ... )
```

... and that will be *better*, but MySQL *is* noted for its "slow" implementation of the "in" operator (but still *nowhere near* as slow as 100 queries!)

Best of all would be to have a table of all Users in your database to start with!